# CakePHP Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

I am tryin to run the following action:

```
public function add() {
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
    // We can save the User data:
    // it should be in $this->request->data['User']

    $user = $this->User->save($this->request->data);

    // If the user was saved, Now we add this information to the data
    // and save the Profile.

    if (!empty($user)) {
        // The ID of the newly created user has been set
        // as $this->User->id.
        $this->request->data['Employee']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;

        // Because our User hasOne Profile, we can access
        // the Profile model through the User model:
        $this->Employee->save($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

When i run this i get the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object
File: /var/www/bloglic-2013/cake/app/Controller/EmployeesController.php
Line: 61
```

How come?

Comment: What is stored in `$this->User` when `save()` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->request->data['Employee']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;`

This line in your code showing that there should already be a relation between `Employee` and `User` model. In `EmployeesController` to save `User` you can try:

```
$this->Employee->User->create();
$this->Employee->User->save($this->request->data);
```

But if your relation not properly defined in models then you can do in `EmployeesController` like below:

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->create();
$this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

and I hope your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You're in the EmployeesController then the save on the User model is not working because either

1.) You don't declare the User model as one of the model that the EmployeesController uses

```
class EmployeesController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array('Employee', 'User');
```

or

2.) Your models don't have the correct relationship. If Employee belongsTo User or vice versa you can do

```
$user = $this->Employee->User->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, but I wouldn't recommend sticking `User` in `$uses`. Try loading the model with `$this->loadModel('User')` or `ClassRegistry::init('User')` to avoid unnecesary use of recurses (that's it, if the employee doesn't have a direct relation to user).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't load model into your controller page. If you not then do this.

You just put your code in controller.

```
public $uses = array('Employee', 'User');
```